# " Unknown Ethereum address " Error calling approve method of Ethereum contract through DApp

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, web3-react, web3modal

I am encountering an error when attempting to call the approve method of a contract on the Ethereum blockchain through my decentralized application (DApp). The error message I'm receiving is:

```
index.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown Ethereum address
{
  "originalError": {}
}
```

This error occurs suddenly without any changes made to my code. Here is the relevant code snippet where the error is being triggered:

```
approve = async () => {
    const tokenContractInstance = await getContractInstance("seedifyToken");
    const addresses = await getContractAddresses();
    const { web3Data, isPaused } = this.state;
    if (isPaused) return this.popup("error", "Staking is paused");
    if (!web3Data?.isLoggedIn) {
    return this.popup("error", "Please connect to metamask");
    }
    console.log("web3Data while approve staking", web3Data);
    console.log("web3Data.account[0] while approve staking", web3Data.accounts[0].address);

    //console.log("web3Data", web3Data.accounts[0]);
    await tokenContractInstance.methods
      .approve(addresses[this.state.activeContract], this.state.totalSupply)
      .send({ from: web3Data.accounts[0].address })
      .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
        //console.log("hash", hash);
        this.setState({ txnHash: hash });
        return this.popup("process");
      })
      .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
        //console.log("receipt", receipt);
        this.getUserData(this.state.web3Data);
        window.removeEventListener("receipt", this.approve);
        return this.popup(
          "success",
          "Your staking is approved . You can invest now !",
          true
        );
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        //console.log(error);
        window.removeEventListener("error", this.withdraw);
        // return this.popup("error", error.message);
        return this.onTransactionError(error);
      });
  };
```

I've checked the address being passed to the approve method to ensure it's valid.
I've reviewed my code for any recent changes that might have caused this error, but I haven't found anything.
I've searched online for similar issues but haven't found a solution that applies to my situation.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!